# Error while using -N option with qsub

Tags: linux, qsub, sungridengine

I tried to use `qsub -N "compile-$*"` in Makefile and it gives the following error 
because $* equals to "compile-obj/linux/flow" in this case.

```
qsub: ERROR! argument to -N option must not contain /
```

The whole command which I am using is:-

```
qsub -P bnormal -N "compile-obj/linux/flow" -cwd -now no -b y -l cputype=amd64 -sync yes -S /bin/sh -e /remote//qsub_files/ -o /remote/qsub_files/
```

Any idea how to include slash in naming while running qsub?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `qsub`, but make just executes what command you supply it. So I suspect you constructed illegal `qsub` command.

Maybe [Automatic-Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) section of GNU make can help you too.

Adding a whole rule to question can help.

Comment: As it is clear from the question that with -N option we can't put slash in job names. But $* returns job names with slashes, hence an error. I was expecting something by which we can pass the job names with slash and it can execute the job.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by manipulating the name passed to -N option by replacing / with -. It works for me. Thanks.